# Regex to extract specific text from nested html tags

Tags: regex, json

I have this text

```
<div id="navbar"><a href="../index.php">Final Fantasy Shrine Forums</a> &gt; <a href="./f-90.html">Downloads</a> &gt; <a href="./f-92.html">Film, Television and Classical Music Download Links</a> &gt; Gott Mit Uns - Ennio Morricone (1969) (FLAC)</div>
```

I want to get this text

```
Gott Mit Uns - Ennio Morricone (1969) (FLAC)
```

I try this regex but doesn't match - I use regex101 and I set Java8 flavor

```
<div\\s*id=\"navbar\"><a.*</a>\\s*&gt;\\s*(.*?)\\s*</div>
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Why do you escape the backslashes and the double quotes? [works for me](https://regex101.com/r/br4Eqz/1)

Comment: Java, JSON, I need to build a pattern for packages, look [HERE](https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?p=509747#post509763), please

Comment: See [updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/namiT6/1)

Comment: @Toto rege is ok, but is not good if you need to implement into JSON file, I used, look [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.ee9347dc3920481c943dfcc48da68e53)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to take the text just before the closing div.

I propose the following regex :

```
.*> &gt; (.*)</div>
```

You can test it here:
https://regex101.com/r/8wgCDG/1